prove Recursive Function $ f(b) = \min(A \setminus f[R_b]) $ preserves ordering in a strong sense (ZFC)
I am trying to solve the following problem using Recursion theorem on well-ordered sets:
Let ( A ) be a well ordered set and let $( B \subseteq A )$. Prove that there exists a unique function $( f: B \to A )$ such that for every $( b \in B )$, the following holds:
$[
f(b) = \min(A \setminus f[R_b])
]$
where $( R_b = \{ x \in B \mid x \lt b \} )$.
For the function from part (b), show that $ f $ preserves the ordering in a strong sense.
I defined a function $F: \bigcup_{b \in B} \{ A \cup \{ d \} \}^{R_b} \to A \cup \{ d \}$
recursively as follows:
$$
F(h) = 
\begin{cases} 
\min \left( A \setminus h[R_b] \right), & \text{if } A \setminus h[R_b] \neq \emptyset \\
d, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
(1) I somehow needs to prove that $
 A \setminus h[R_b] \neq \emptyset 
$
then by recursion theorem we know that there exists a unique $f:B \to A$ s.t.
$
f(b) = F(f \rvert_b) = \min(A \setminus f[R_b])
$
Even with assuming the previous, I struggled to continue.
I wanted to prove that:
$
f[B] = A
\quad \text{or} \quad
f[B] = R_b
$
Can you help me with (1) and some general guidelines for the proof.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
